# Link on my website to facebook message a page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, web, message, facebook-page

I would like to embed a link that will open site visitor's browser with their facebook account in "New Message" writing mode with the "to:" field already pointing to my Facebook page.

Is there a way to do this?

It's a wordpress site, so if there is already a plugin that can do this I'd be happy to know which (without asking the visitor for permissions to a facebook app).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the FB.ui send dialog:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

There is a parameter called "to" where you could try to add the ID of your Facebook Page. Although i am not sure if it works for Pages, but it´s worth trying.